# Bundling with one file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, asp.net-mvc-3, bundling-and-minification

I have a view with several partial views. The view loads several javascript file as a single bundle. but one js file differ based on the partial view.

Can i bundle one file in my partial, will it improve performance. 
or how can i minify that file in order to improve performance.

Comment: Your question is about ASP.NET MVC, right? If yes, try to add [asp.net-mvc] tag to get more answers from .net community.

Comment: yes. i am working on asp.net mvc project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd rather have a single bundle containing all your resources. Even if they are not used on each views, the fact that you have a single bundle that will be downloaded **only once** and cached subsequently will be better compared to have different bundles for the different views resulting on different HTTP requests to fetch them. Remember that minifying and `gzip`ing the bundle would greatly reduce its size, so it shouldn't make big difference when initially downloading this bundle.